# Bootbox ASP MVC Razor partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I am using bootbox widget to display bootstrap modal.

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

What i need is to load Razor partial view in bootbox modal

This works ok

```
$(".permissions-popup").click(function () {
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Icons description.",
        message: '<div class="alert">Hello</div>',
        buttons: {
            main: {
                label: "Close",
                className: "btn-primary",
                callback: function () {
                }
            }
        },
        className: "modal-large"
    }
   );
});
```

But when i try something like this

```
$(".permissions-popup").click(function () {
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Icons description.",
        message: '@Html.Partial("_ConentInfo")',
        buttons: {
            main: {
                label: "Close",
                className: "btn-primary",
                callback: function () {
                }
            }
        },
        className: "modal-large"
    }
   );
});
```

It doesn not work i got error like this

**SyntaxError: unterminated string literal**

Is ti possible to load partial view in bootbox widget, i know i can to that with plain bootstrap modal, but i need bootbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Inside razor view:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

then you can create a javascript object:

```
var bootboxDialogMessage = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Html.Partial("_ConentInfo").ToString().Trim('"'))));
```

and use it in your even inside a script file `bootboxDialogMessage`

Note: This adds unnecessary overhead imo, just go with your first way.
I am using this only in a case that I am passing a model in my partial view.

Comment: Nice minor fix, i am gettting some strane " before and after content?

Comment: bootboxDialogMessage.substr(1).slice(0, -1)  only this is somthing i dont like :(