# Load partialview or viewcomponent using bootbox.dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a list of categories, I want to do the registration and editing using popup, for this I am using the [bootbox.dialog](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-custom-dialog), I created a partialview that has the form for registration / editing, the problem that I am not able to load the partialview in bootbox.dialog, first I tried this way:

Categorias.cshtml

```
    function CadAltCategoria(cod) {

        var strTit = (cod == 0) ? 'Cadastro de categoria' : 'Edição de categoria';

        bootbox.dialog({
            message: '@Html.Raw( await Html.PartialAsync("CategoriaCadAlt"))',
            title: strTit,
            className: "modal-darkorange",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Salvar",
                    className: "btn-blue",
                    callback: function () { alert('teste'); }
                },
                "Cancelar": {
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function () { }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

It does not load the partialview, and the result is:

[image: popup generated]

instead of the contents of the partialview, the message "**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewBuffer**"

My partialview looks like this:

CategoriaCadAlt.cshtml

```
<div id="popCadAltCateg" style="display:none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Content" rows="5" required=""></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this post "[Bootbox ASP MVC Razor partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617852/bootbox-asp-mvc-razor-partial-view)" speaking of the subject, but did not solve the problem, the result was:

[image: Popup 2]

How can I do this, I do not want to have to navigate to another page to register / edit a record, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so:

in Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult ReturnPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("youPartialView");
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    function CadAltCategoria(cod) {

        var url = '@Url.Action("ReturnPartialView", "YouController")';
        var strTit = (cod == 0) ? 'Cadastro de categoria' : 'Edição de categoria';

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            bootbox.dialog({
                message: data,
                title: strTit,
                className: "modal-darkorange",
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: "Salvar",
                        className: "btn-blue",
                        callback: function () { alert('teste'); }
                    },
                    "Cancelar": {
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function () { }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    }
```

This way you can pass an id for editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `Html.Raw`, you will get the HTML markup generated by `PartialAsync` method, but since the generated HTML is multi line, it is going to throw a script error.

```
var msg ='await Html.PartialAsync("CategoriaCadAlt")'
//use msg for message 
// Oh no! This give script error :(
```

You can use [temporal literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) strings (ES6) to deal with this multi line situation

```
var msg = `@await Html.PartialAsync("CategoriaCadAlt"))`;
// use msg  for message
```

Another option is , you should consider executing the partial view call as part of your view, which will result in the HTML markup and use that as your bootbox message.

One way tot do that is, execute the partial view call inside your razor view and keep it inside a container div ( hidden) and on your click event handler, read that container element and get the inner html of that (which is the HTML generated from the partial view)

```
<div id="my-partial" style="display: none;">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("CategoriaCadAlt")
</div>
```

and in the script

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function (e) {
    var msg = $("#my-partial").html();
    bootbox.dialog({
        message: msg,
        title: 'dd',
        className: "modal-darkorange",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Salvar",
                className: "btn-blue",
                callback: function () { alert('teste'); }
            },
            "Cancelar": {
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function () { }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

With this approach, the partial view code is always executed when the original page renders.

Another option is to make an ajax call to the server and get the HTML markup as the result of an action method and use that. You need to expose an action method which returns your partial view.